# Popup Window animation changed programatically in Android

Tags: android, animation

I already have a `PopupWindow` and a defined XML scale animation in `res/anim/` that is applied on show and on dismiss of that popup window. But the case is I want to change `pivotX` and `pivotY` of the style of animation dynamically so it starts (grows) from different points of the screen.

So either I'm able change `pivotX` and `pivotY` dynamically in `res/anim/in.xml` or create new `ScaleAnimation` and apply it. I cannot see how to do the first option, and unfortunately the latter doesn't work when I write:

```
public class MyPopup {

    private PopupWindow popupWindow;

    private Integer growFromX;
    private Integer growFromY;

    public MyPopup(Integer growFromX, Integer growFromY) {
        if (growFromX != null && growFromY != null) {
            this.growFromX = growFromX.intValue();
            this.growFromY = growFromY.intValue();
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.activity
                .getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                        Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.map_selector_dialog_layout, null);

        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                (float) this.growFromX, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                (float) this.growFromY);
        scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(4000);
        popupView.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);

        this.popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        this.popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

It doesn't have to be WindowPopup. I can use `Dialog` or whatever so I can I achieve such a behaviour. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

few things to tweak to make your code work:

- set width and height for the 'popupView' inside the 'popupWindow'
- set an interpolator for the ScaleAnimation
- either use

  ```
  popupView.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  popupView.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
  ```

  or set the start time of you animation before calling 'setAnimation' and make sure the view's parent gets invalidated when the animation starts
- replace

  ```
  this.popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  ```

  with

  ```
  this.popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height);
  ```

  where width and height have to be bigger than the dimensions of the 'popupView' during and after the scaling process. with LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT the ScaleAnimation won't work.

hope it helps